# The formula for the X coordinate is radius + (radius * cos(degree)) and The formula for the Y coordinate is radius + (radius * sin(degree)).

Tags: trigonometry

I found in some websites,  the formula they provide me get calculate the coordinate X and Y as below: May I know how to derive it ? Why they need to add radius after $\text{radius} * \cos(\text{degree})$? According Parametric form in equation of circle, it should be the center of the circle, why it put radius?

The formula for the $X$ coordinate is $\text{radius} + (\text{radius} * \cos(\text{degree}))$.

The formula for the $Y$ coordinate is $\text{radius} + (\text{radius} * \sin(\text{degree}))$.

(https://css-tricks.com/creating-a-clock-with-the-new-css-sin-and-cos-trigonometry-functions/)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, a *circle* is parameterized like this:

$$
\begin{cases}
x = x_c + r\cos(t) \\
y = y_c + r\sin(t)
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \quad
\text{with} \; t \in [0,2\pi)
$$

where, in your specific case, $(x_c,y_c) = (r,r)$ was assumed.

On the other hand, if I were to design a clock, I would parameterize it like this:

$$
\begin{cases}
x = 0 + 1\sin(t) \\
y = 0 + 1\cos(t)
\end{cases}
\quad \quad \quad
\text{with} \; t \in [0,2\pi)
$$

such that zero is on the vertical and positive rotations are clockwise.

```
{h, m, s, cs} = {12, 6, 3, 70};
time = 3600 h + 60 m + s + cs/100;

circle = {Sin[t], Cos[t]};
hours = Table[Text[Style[ToString[6 t/π], 16], 0.80 circle], {t, π/6, 2π, π/6}];
ticks = Table[{circle, If[Mod[30 t/π, 5] == 0, 0.90, 0.95] circle}, {t, π/30, 2π, π/30}];

Graphics[{Black, Thickness[0.010], Circle[{0, 0}, 1],
          Black, Thickness[0.002], Line[ticks], 
          Black, Thickness[0.010], Line[{{0, 0}, 0.95 circle /. t -> 2π time/3600}],
          Black, Thickness[0.010], Line[{{0, 0}, 0.65 circle /. t -> 2π time/43200}],
          Red, Thickness[0.005], Line[{{0, 0}, 0.95 circle /. t -> 2π time/60}]}, 
          Epilog -> hours]
```

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad$[image]

Answer (score 0):

The formula for the $x$ coordinate is
$$\text{x-coordinate of center of circle } + \text{radius of circle} * \cos(\text{degree}).$$

Similarly $y-$coordinate, $\sin$ etc.